# Creating SVG map from geometry stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql, svg

I have a group of geometries stored in MySQl (as polygon and as well-known text) representing counties.

I can build a table of geometries and color codes after querying some county data (say GDP per capita).

What is the best way to export this as an SVG map? 
I cannot find any reference to SVG conversion in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: I am not at all clear what your situation is.... You say you have a table of geometries (let me assume X,Y coordinates and possibly elevation, and now you want to output groups of vectors in SVG format? And expect there is a native MySQL function to do this for you?

Comment: Sorry to be imprecise. yes i have a table of polygons and i can attach color codes to them after a separate dataset and i would like to export the lot as a Choropleth in SVG format. I have just found out that OpenLayers includes a format function which can parse KMT (in .js). I guess I can get somewhere with this... but other ideas are always welcome!